# Send ERC20 token from a forwarder contract address to another address

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, contract-debugging, smart-contract-wallets

I am having difficulty spending the funds in a smart contract address.

The smart contract address was generated using an ETH forwarder smart contract - https://github.com/primozkocevar/SigWallet-ERC20/blob/master/contracts/Forwarder.sol.

I'm stuck at sending ERC20 tokens out of the address - https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x53c021a405c7af363ecf69ef22ea8e5614d0d1ff.

Can someone guide/help me on this ?

Comment: Which function are you trying to call?

Comment: flushTokens function in the forwarder contract @Ismael

Comment: I have been able to fix the issue, I had to change the modifier restriction of the Forwarder contract

Comment: That's nice I have just checked the contracts in remix.ethereum.org against the FixedSupply token and it worked when calling `flushTokens` from the same account that deployed the contract because it uses the onlyParent modifier. If you solved your question it would be nice if you can write an answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for your feedback. 

The problem was the modifier in the flushToken function. I had to use the deployer account to call the function.

`function flushTokens(address tokenContractAddress) public onlyParent {
  }`

Comment: You can write that as an answer, a comment doesn't have nice formatting for code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by first ensuring that the deployer of this account was the caller of the flushToken function in the contract

```
function flushTokens(address tokenContractAddress) public onlyParent {
    ERC20Interface instance = ERC20Interface(tokenContractAddress);
    uint256 forwarderBalance = instance.balanceOf(address(this));
    if (forwarderBalance == 0) {
      revert();
    }
    if (!instance.transfer(parentAddress, forwarderBalance)) {
      revert();
    }
    // fire of an event just for the record!
    emit TokensFlushed(address(this), forwarderBalance, tokenContractAddress);
  }
```

To make things more flexible, I removed the `onlyParent` modifier for this function, so that it can be called from any account.